# UNSUPPORTED_CLIENT: TLS 1.0 has been disabled in this organization

Tags: apex, soap-api

I am doing the SOAP Trailhead tutorials from the link: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/api_basics/units/api_basics_soap. While executing the SOAP web service I am getting the below error.

***Note: I am already using Prod org.***, Since I am administrator so that I already have 
Permissions Required

A user must have the following permissions:

- View the CRUC setting: View Setup and Configuration
- Activate or Deactivate the CRUC setting: Customize Application and Modify All Data

Here is the error message

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sf="urn:fault.enterprise.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>sf:UNSUPPORTED_CLIENT</faultcode>
         <faultstring>UNSUPPORTED_CLIENT: TLS 1.0 has been disabled in this organization. Please use TLS 1.1 or higher when connecting to Salesforce using https.</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <sf:UnexpectedErrorFault xsi:type="sf:UnexpectedErrorFault">
               <sf:exceptionCode>UNSUPPORTED_CLIENT</sf:exceptionCode>
               <sf:exceptionMessage>TLS 1.0 has been disabled in this organization. Please use TLS 1.1 or higher when connecting to Salesforce using https.</sf:exceptionMessage>
               <sf:upgradeURL>https://ap5.salesforce.com/secur/weakhttps.jsp?l=1</sf:upgradeURL>
               <sf:upgradeMessage>Stronger security is required</sf:upgradeMessage>
            </sf:UnexpectedErrorFault>
         </detail>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**I am using Username and password+security token.**

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are connecting to Salesforce from SOAP UI, so this SOAP UI must be TLSv1.1 or above.

Reach to SoapUI-5.2.1 VMOPTIONS file which is under `SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin`

[image: SOAP UI PATH]

Add entry like this:

**-Dsoapui.https.protocols=SSLv3,TLSv1.1**

This is a sample entries in that file:

```
-XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=20
-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=40
-Xms128m
-Xmx1000m
-Dsoapui.properties=soapui.properties
-Dsoapui.home=C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1/bin
-Dsoapui.ext.libraries=C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1/bin/ext
-Dsoapui.ext.listeners=C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1/bin/listeners
-Dsoapui.ext.actions=C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1/bin/actions
-Dsoapui.https.protocols=SSLv3,TLSv1.1
-Dwsi.dir=C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1/wsi-test-tools
-Djava.library.path=C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1/bin
-Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true
-splash:SoapUI-Spashscreen.png
```

Comment: cool, Works for me !! Thanks you. Just need to restart the SOAP UI post `-Dsoapui.https.protocols=SSLv3,TLSv1.1` changes